# How to create a workflow in five9

Tags: workflow, whatsapp, five9

Im trying to create a simple whatsapp workflow in five9 where I have to send a couple of responses to customer and take decision based on those responses. After a lot of searching I couldn't find a documentation regarding the workflow controls. Is there any documentation or sample workflows I can use to kickstart me task? Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.